# Rails application as a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Suppose I have a rails application. What should I do to create a gem from it and distribute it to heroku (for example)?

Comment: you want to create a gem or make an application in heroku?

Comment: I want to make a gem so I can write `gem install my-gem` and after that my application should be running

Comment: you want to creata a gem that will have an application inside it?

Comment: yes, something like that

Comment: Distributing a gem on heroku doesn't really make any sense. Do you mean github maybe?

Comment: I mean that someone can just type `gem install my-gem` and the application is running and can be visited from the browser